# Write regex to replace html paragraph according to the attribute of a specific tag

Tags: html, regex, tags

I have a string containing regular text mixed with html how do i write a regex so I can replace specific p(paragraph) tags with regular text here's an example of what I want to replace:

```
    <p style="padding-left: 30px;">someText</p>
```

the regular expression should match and replace this specific tag with whitespace matching the padding-left attribute + the innerText.

Btw. I am doing the regex parsing in C#

Comment: What language are you doing the regex parsing in?

Comment: Darn .. I came up with a great JavaScript solution, but I don't know `C#` and it doesn't seem compatible at all

Comment: What if `p` has other attributes? what if `p` style has other style rules apart from `padding-left`?

Comment: maybe I can if you would care to show it? :-)

Comment: there will only be regular p or p with padding left

Comment: Don't do HTML parsing with regex. Please!

Comment: I do realize it is not the best sollution, but unfortunately it is nessesary in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an html/xml parser instead, but assuming there are no nested tags and your attributes and styles are always defined in the same order, you can use this:

```
text.replace(/<p.*?style=.*?padding-left: (\d+).*?>(.*?)<\/p>/, function (x) {
    console.log((new Array(Number(arguments[1]))).join(' ') + arguments[2]);
});
```

Comment: but does html xml parsers handle regular text as well?

Comment: @KennO they can .. definitely.  It's not like you're doing any parsing on the regular text.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking me to write in the answer

Comment: Oh I just think I should definitely use an xml/html parser so it was just if you wanted the points for your answer

Comment: Well I did say that in the answer <_<